# Verbatim text search doesn't work

Tags: bug, search

I'd say the search works incorrectly, but verbatim is verbatim, which means it doesn't actually work as intended.

When looking for a phrase `This post does not cite any references or sources`, search shows me 10 results, omitting `This`, `not` and `or`. I know, because search optimization, right? But when I distrustingly looked for `"This post does not cite any references or sources"`, I got no results. Right when there were just about ten of them. Not so verbatim after all?

[image: click for no sore eyes]

Comment: And to cite some references and sources⁽[¹](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=This+post+does+not+cite+any+references+or+sources)⁾,⁽[²](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22This+post+does+not+cite+any+references+or+sources%22)⁾.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is that you excluded a `.` and instead put `sources`, not `sources.`

This is expected behavior of the system, because `sources` and `sources.` are two different words. It doesn't treat the period as another word, it becomes a part of the word `sources`. Therefore, by not adding the `.`, it looks for *only* posts that match `blah.... sources` not `blah.... sources.`.

Comment: Interesting behavior. `.` is a punctuation symbol, and therefore cannot be part of a word. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @user1306322 I'm not quite sure, but that's the way the system treats it. Maybe it's somehow adding the period as a special character as part of the word?

Comment: This system works in a way different from what my previous experience with text searching tells me it should. I usually trust SE with how technology should be, but not this time.

Comment: Fully agreed with user here -- this functionality is not what someone would expect. I would assume that searching for "This post does not cite any references or source" would also find "This post does not cite any references or source**s**" or "This post does not cite any references or source**s.**"

Comment: Or using wildcard search notation `*This post does not cite any references or sources*` would be the expected search pattern.